# Как выровнять картинку по центру блока?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок "coffee", как выровнять картинку по центру?

CSS:

```
.coffee {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0.3px grey;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 86px;
        margin-right: 210px;
        background-image: url(../images/coffee.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ```background-position: center```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `background-position`. Максимально подробно описано [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position)

```css
    background-position: center;
```

```css
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: center;
```